# iPhone load more tableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios

So I Have a design question for you.  Basically I have an app in which I fetch 20 items from a server when the app loads, and displays them in a table view.  I also have a loading table cell that appears in the last cell.  What I want to do is when that cell appears, load the next 20 items and add them to the list and reload the table.

What recommendations do you guys have for doing something like this?  Should I automatically fire off the request when the cell appears?  Or should I wait for something else to do this?  Any input would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I'd fire off the request as soon as the cell appears. In fact, I'd consider firing the request before the cell appears - around cell 15 or so? That way the user is waiting for less time with a loading cell displayed.

However, that all depends on how big your data set is - if it's lots of data to get the next 20 rows I'd put something like 'press here for more results' and wait for the user's input to fire off the request.

The best way to find out which gives the best user experience is to do a quick user test - ask people who might be your customers to test the app and see which they seem happiest with. And take a look at apps like yours - what do they do - if they have set a precedent with your customers, perhaps you should try to follow that?

Comment: I think that this is what I am going to end up doing.  It seems like it will be very seamless this way.  Question though, how do I make the table save it's scroll position so when it reloads it doesn't go back to the top?

Comment: I didn't think it scrolled to the top on a reload?

Comment: It does, but I figured out how to save the index and scroll to that position without animating.  Thanks for the help, this works!  :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use following test code;

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    totalElements = pageNumber*kNumberofElementsPerPage;
    int noOfrows = totalElements>[customerArray count]?[customerArray count]:totalElements+1;
    return noOfrows;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if(indexPath.row == totalElements&&totalElements!=0){
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"loadMoreCell"];
        if(cell == nil){
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"loadMoreCell"];
        }
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Load More records";
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Showing %d of %d records",totalElements,[customerArray count]];
        return cell;
    }
    ......
    ......
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(indexPath.row == totalElements){
        pageNumber++;
        [customerTableView reloadData];
        return;
    }
    ......
    ......
}
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I think that I am going to dynamically load it as the user scrolls, so they don't need to press anything.  :)

Comment: eg: First it will list 10 rows in a table view. last row is "Load More Records", if you click on it, then it will list 10 more rows. Dynamically it will happen

Comment: Well yeah, I got it working so it will fire if the user  gets within 5 rows of the bottom.  This would probably work as well...

Comment: @gabaum10: For now my XMLParser is parsing 100 entries. I'd like to do the same as you did: automatically load more entries as soon the last row is reached. Can you help me with some code? Thank you in advance.